# Child's `height: 100%;` is not taking parent's full height, why?

Tags: html, css

Both parent and child have `box-sizing: border-box;`. According to MDN:

> <percentage> Defines the height as a percentage of the containing block's height.

Then the child's height should be `500px` as well, but obviously it's not, it has the height of the **parent's content height**, *not* **parent's height**. Having tried this code on many browsers including IE, they all work the same, why is that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ress/dist/ress.min.css" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #000;
      }
      .parent {
        border: 50px solid blue;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background: green;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .child {
        background: red;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you have set `padding: 20px` for the `parent` element, so your `child` div doesn't reach 100% height.

Comment: But the parent has `box-sizing: border-box;`, it's height includes padding as well, so parent's height is still `500px`, according to the doc: "<percentage> defines the height as a percentage of the containing block's height.", the child's height should be `500px` and overflowed.

Comment: @Wenfang yeah, but it doesn't matter, the fact is that respect to the content of the parent the 100% is smaller. (remember that the background property also makes the padding colored!)

Comment: _“but obviously it's not, it has the height of the parent's content height, not parent's height.”_ - you quoted the part saying it refers to the _containing block_  yourself, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block explains, _“Most often, the containing block is the content area of an element's nearest block-level ancestor […]”_ - so where do you see any actual discrepancy here?

Comment: Yoshi has explained well in their answer, have a look at it. But if you don't want your element to get bounded by it's parent's padding then, set parent's position to relative and child's to absolute with left and top set to 0, but this is also not sufficient and it will result in child with width and height having 400px, because the parent's border will be the limits to the child element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood the term `containing block`, I thought it would be the parent, but not really, there's much more into this.

I had to dig into the [W3C standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) to find out:

> Definition of "containing block"
>
> The position and size of an element's box(es) are sometimes calculated relative to a certain rectangle, called the *containing block* of the element.
>
> The containing block in which the *root element* lives is a rectangle called the initial containing block.
>
> **For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the *content edge* of the nearest block container ancestor box.**
> ...

Answer (score 4):

Using [`border-box`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-shapes-1/#border-box) just defines how the given height should apply with respect to padding and border values. In your example this results in a outer height of 500px for `.parent`.

Basically it's just a convenience method - so that you don't have to calculate the actual height yourself (as in the times before `border-box` was a thing). Without it, you'd need to define `height: 360px;` to achieve an outer height of 500px.

But `.child`'s *containing block* still resides *inside* the area delimited by `.parent`'s padding. And percentage heights are calculated with respect to that containing block ([ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)). Which in this example are the same `360px` you would have used without `border-box` on `.parent`.

Comment: Very well explained, child element will always remain inside the content area of parent element, bounded by its parent's padding.

Answer (score 1):

this is, as you can see, because you have set a padding to the parent. so its 100% will not take padding into account.

```css
body {
   background: #000;
}
.parent {
   border: 50px solid blue;
   padding: 20px;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background: green;
   overflow: auto;
}
.child {
   background: red;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

it is not clear what you are trying to do, but if you want to make the child fill the entire parent a solution could be this:

```css
body {
   background: #000;
}
.parent {
   border: 50px solid blue;
   /* padding: 20px; simply remove the padding */
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   background: green;
   overflow: auto;
}
.child {
   background: red;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

this is because when the property `box-sizing` is set to `border-box` the padding becomes to being taken into account from the properties `height`, `width`... but this doesn't mean that the padding disappears, the padding is simply acts on the content of the parent.

remember this!
[image: content]

Comment: This answer didn't really explain why, it's more like showing behavior, what I'm asking for is why.

Comment: see my recent edit, hope this can explain better what i meant.

Answer (score -1):

Because You use child div in Parent and Parent height is 500px and You use child height 100 % That's why child get 500px Height due to parent.

Comment: Please do read the description and try the code, the height is not `500px`.